# How can I deploy a IIB application using the command line like it is done by the toolkit (gui)?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I would like to execute exactly the same steps done by the IIB Toolkit deploy (right click the application and Deploy...to an integration server) but using the command line.
In my humble opinion it is an action that does trigger several steps/commands.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the commands to deploy an application to integration server:

1. Create a bar file using [mqsicreatebar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an19540_.html) command.
2. Deploy the created bar file from step 1 using [mqsideploy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an28520_.html) command.

Comment: Rohan : Thanks for the help. I have typed a few commands 'to create the bar' and then 'deploy it', command line but I had some problems. I will come back as soon I made the deployment working using the command line.

Comment: Please note that `mqsicreatebar` starts an Eclipse/Toolkit instance in the background (this is why it is so slow) and creates a `.metadata` directory. I had once a problem that it overwrote the `.metadata` of my interactive Eclipse/Toolkit. On the command line (especially Jenkins) I use now always [mqsipackagebar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc31720_.html) or more precise the `FlowRendererBAR` Java class, which speeds up the build process enormously.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command:

```
mqsideploy node_name -e server_name -a <bar_file_location>_file.bar
```